# Pass member function as callback to constructor other class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, callback, std, functor

Hi I want to pass member function as argument to constructor other class. I tried lot solutions but all given me fail.
So..
First class..

```
class WebSocketsServerRunner : public WebSocketsServer {
   private:
       ThreadController<uint8_t> threads = ThreadController<uint8_t>();
       SensorsState sensorsState;

    void notifyClient(uint8_t clientNumber) { // this is the callback
        String message = sensorsState.readAsJSON();
        WebSocketsServer::sendTXT(clientNumber, message);
    }

    void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {

        // solution bellow doesn't work!
        Thread<uint8_t>* thread = new Thread<uint8_t>(static_cast<int>(num),  &WebSocketsServerRunner::notifyClient, num, 5000);

        threads.add(thread);

    } 
};
```

And Thread constructor declaration:

```
    Thread(int _id, void (*callback)(void) = NULL, long _interval = 0);
    Thread(int _id, void (*callback)(Arg), Arg arg, long _interval = 0);
```

Where Arg is `template <typename Arg>`

I tried everything.. std::bind, &CLASS_NAME::METHOD_NAME, static_cast but nothing works..

Compile gives me :

`no known conversion for argument 2 from 'void (WebSocketsServerRunner::*)(uint8_t) {aka void (WebSocketsServerRunner::*)(unsigned char)}' to 'void (*)(unsigned char)'`

...

`no matching function for call to 'Thread<unsigned char>::Thread(int, void (WebSocketsServerRunner::*)(uint8_t), uint8_t&, int)'`

Comment: The biggest problem is in the `Thread` class, because pointers to non-static member functions are ***not*** equal to non-member function pointers. I suggest you take a look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to begin help you with that problem. Continuing with [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) might be wise.

Comment: `auto const bind = std::bind(&WebSocketsServerRunner::notifyClient, this, std::placeholders::_1);
            Thread<uint8_t>* thread = new Thread<uint8_t>(static_cast<int>(num),  bind, num, 5000); ` 

gives me 

`no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (WebSocketsServerRunner::*)(unsigned char)>(WebSocketsServerRunner*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>' to 'void (*)(unsigned char)'` :(

Comment: Can you modify `Thread`? You cannot probably do this otherwise. There's no way I know of to bind your object to this method if `Thread` expects a function pointer.

Comment: I can modify ;) but how? std::function instead of function pointer?

Comment: Classic approach is to pass a pointer to your class into the parameters of the call back and call your member function from the static call back. The problem is the compiler is doing that for you when your thread expects a static signature without your this pointer. But really why are you not using std::thread which allows you to use function objects  which means you can use std::function and std::bind as needed?

Comment: I am creating firmawe for ESP8266 wifi module and I think, that there classic std::threads won't working, beacuse this module not support really multithreading...

Comment: @MateuszZ Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to member functions have different syntax than ordinary function pointers:

```
void(*function)();                  // pointer to function
void(YourClass::*memberFunction)(); // pointer to member function
```

Reason behind is that member functions have an additional, hidden/transparent parameter accepting the object the function is called on and is presented to you as `this` pointer.

So calling a member function differs as well (you need an object to call the function on):

```
void(YourClass::*memberFunction)() = &YourClass::someFunction;
YourClass instance;
YourClass* pointer = &instance;
(instance.*memberFunction)();
(pointer->*memberFunction)();
```

Be aware that both `.*` and `->*` operators have lower precedence than function call operator `()` (if it was a good decision might be arguable, but it is as it is...), so you *need* the parentheses.

The following I show *only for illustration* of the nature of member functions, be aware that it actually is **undefined behaviour** (but it is very likely to work) – **don't *ever* use this in productive code**:

```
void(*functionR)(YourClass&)
    = reinterpret_cast<&void(*)(YourClass&)(&YourClass::someFunction);
void(*functionP)(YourClass*)
    = reinterpret_cast<&void(*)(YourClass*)(&YourClass::someFunction);
YourClass instance;
YourClass* pointer = &instance;
functionR(instance);
functionP(pointer);
```

The interesting aspect of is that both reference and pointer should do the trick, revealing that under the hoods, references – if instanciated at all – are nothing more than pointers as well, solely with specific rules applied (so in the end, syntactic sugar).

Above reveals as well, though, that to call a member function, even if you *illegally* use an ordinary function pointer, you still need an object on which you can call the function!

So which are the options?

`static` member functions do not have the transparent `this` function parameter, i. e. they can be used just like any ordinary function:

```
static void notifyClient(uint8_t clientNumber)
// ^^^ (!)
{
     WebSocketsServerRunner& instance = selectById(clientNumber);
     String message = instance.sensorsState.readAsJSON();
     WebSocketsServer::sendTXT(clientNumber, message);
}
```

If you cannot get the instance using the client number, you'll have to modify the `Thread` class such that it holds the object to call the function on as well.

Most *generic*, not necessarily the safest one, though, is using a `void*` pointer:

```
class Thread
{
    void(*function)(void*);
    void* parameter;

     void run()
     {
         function(parameter);
     }
};
```

You now could use static member and normal functions, but you need to cast the parameter back to get the instance, additionally you cannot use smart pointers for safe memory management. Better approach:

```
template <typename T> 
class Thread
{
    std::function<void(T*)>;
    std::shared_ptr<T> instance;

     void run()
     {
         function(instance.get());
     }
public:
     template <typename F>
     Thread(F function, std::shared_ptr<T>& instance)
         : function(function), instance(instance)
     { }
};
```

The interesting part of is that you can store both pointer to member function as well as free-standing functions in the std::function object. Another variant:

```
template <typename T> 
class Thread
{
    T t;

     void run()
     {
         t();
     }
public:
     Thread(T&& t)
         : t(std::move(t))
     { }
};
```

This one could be feeded with lambdas:

```
Thread t([&instance]() { instance.doSomething(); });
```

<s>It possibly might be an interesting alternative to use `std::thread` directly:</s>

```
class WebSocketsServerRunner
{
public:
    static void run(uint8_t clientNumber)
    {
        WebSocketsServerRunner instance;
        for(;;)
        {
            // do whatever your Thread class did
        }
    }
};

std::thread t10(&WebSocketsServerRunner::run, 10U);
std::thread t12(&WebSocketsServerRunner::run, 12U);
```

*Edit: according to your comments, not suitable...*